# How to break lines in a node of a tikz tree

Tags: tikz-trees

This is the code I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
                            -- +(0,-5pt)
                            -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}

\Tree   [.Fibres
        [.Natural
            [.Animal Silk
            ]
            [.Vegetable
                [.Cotton\\Linen\\Hemp\\Ramie\\Jute ]
            ]
            [.Mineral   Asbestos ]
        ]
        [.Man-made
            [.{Natural Polymers} 
                [.XYZ ]
                [.XYZ ]
                [.XYZ ]
            ]
            [.{Synthetic Polymers}
                [.XYZ ]
                [.XYZ ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives me a good tree. But I want to have "Cotton Linen Hemp Ramie Jute" displayed one below another instead of right next to each other. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I edited your question title to describe your question more clearly. Things like "how to do this" could stand for virtually anything and doesn't help to spur interest or find the question if one has the same problem. Feel free to change it again.

Answer (score 8):

`forest` is a powerful tree-drawing tool, although [Jesse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220754/) has the advantage of simplicity in this case. However, for what it is worth, here is the same tree with `forest`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-15pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    if n=2{
      if ={equal(n_children("!u"),3)}{calign with current}{}}{},
  }
  [Fibres
        [Natural
            [Animal
              [Silk
              ]
            ]
            [Vegetable
                [Cotton\\Linen\\Hemp\\Ramie\\Jute
                ]
            ]
            [Mineral
              [Asbestos
              ]
            ]
        ]
        [Man-made
            [Natural Polymers
                [XYZ
                ]
                [XYZ
                ]
                [XYZ
                ]
            ]
            [Synthetic Polymers
                [XYZ
                ]
                [XYZ
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest alignments]

Comment: Great you have this `forest` alternative.

Comment: Oops! @cfr Animal Silk are parent and child relation, so is Mineral Asbestos in the OP's output.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks! I tried to compile both the trees in your code - should have re-checked the OP's, obviously!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will learn about 'forest' and use it next time.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.  Define a local node that has its own style, displayed below.

```
\tikzset{my node/.style={text width=2cm,align=center}}  % left or right are available
```

Furthermore, the `vegetable` was not centered and that is improved by setting equal length for the neighbors, like

```
\makebox[\widthof{Vegetable}]{Animal}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

OP's result ---

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
                            -- +(0,-5pt)
                            -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}

\Tree   [.Fibres
        [.Natural
            [.Animal Silk
            ]
            [.Vegetable
                [.Cotton\\Linen\\Hemp\\Ramie\\Jute ]
            ]
            [.Mineral   Asbestos ]
        ]
        [.Man-made
            [.{Natural Polymers} 
                [.XYZ ]
                [.XYZ ]
                [.XYZ ]
            ]
            [.{Synthetic Polymers}
                [.XYZ ]
                [.XYZ ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

\end{tikzpicture}


\medskip

Proposed result ---

\tikzset{my node/.style={text width=2cm,align=center}}


\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
                            -- +(0,-5pt)
                            -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree   [.Fibres
        [.Natural
            [.\makebox[\widthof{Vegetable}]{Animal} Silk
            ]
            [.Vegetable
                [.\node[my node]{                   % <--- here
                Cotton\\Linen\\Hemp\\Ramie\\Jute};
                ]
            ]
            [.\makebox[\widthof{Vegetable}]{Mineral}   Asbestos ]
        ]
        [.Man-made
            [.{Natural Polymers} 
                [.XYZ ]
                [.XYZ ]
                [.XYZ ]
            ]
            [.{Synthetic Polymers}
                [.XYZ ]
                [.XYZ ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just set `align=center` for the picture?

Comment: @cfr Are you referring to the centering problem of `Vegetable` that I did not observed until you mentioned it.

Comment: I just wondered if you needed a special node style or whether you could just apply `align=center` to the lot. Since the cotton/linen/... node includes explicit line breaks, the width specification might not really be needed? [Whatever problem you noticed with `Vegetable` on account of my comment was in no way due to any insight of mine ;).] Afraid I forgot to (+1) earlier...

Comment: I learned that special node from reading the manual; without text width specification will cause messy overlapping. As always, your comments make me think and learn. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about that ;). Interesting about the overlapping. Your current code doesn't compile for me, though. `\widthof` is undefined?

Comment: You need \usepackage{calc}. Sorry, forgot to add this package after adding new feature.

Comment: @ShyamSrinivasaraghavan Please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the greyed-out check mark to the top left of the answer. This helps other users find it, gives the author points and also gives you points.

Comment: @ShyamSrinivasaraghavan You are welcome.